# OneSignal for Android in NativeScript. Wont load library

Tags: android, nativescript, onesignal

I'm trying to implement OneSignal Push Notifications in my NativeScript application for both Android and iOS. For iOS I got it working just fine with CocoaPods. However, when I am trying to compile the OneSignal package for Android, I cant get access to the com.onesignal.

So first off, I've added this to my App_Resources/Android/App.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.+@aar'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:+'
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:+"
}

android {  
  defaultConfig {  
    generatedDensities = []  
    applicationId = "<HIDDEN>"  
    multiDexEnabled true
    manifestPlaceholders = [manifestApplicationId: "<HIDDEN>", onesignal_app_id: "<HIDDEN>", onesignal_google_project_number: "<HIDDEN>"]
  }  
  aaptOptions {  
    additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"  
  }  
}
```

I've the run the command `tns build android`
This gives me this line: `:prepareComOnesignalOneSignal311Library UP-TO-DATE`

My app.js looks like this:

```
var application = require("application");

application.on(application.launchEvent, function (args) {
    if (args.android) {
        console.dump(com.onesignal.OneSignal);
    } 
});

// iOS specific configuration
if (application.ios) {

    var __extends = this.__extends || function (d, b) {
        for (var p in b) if (b.hasOwnProperty(p)) d[p] = b[p];
        function __() { this.constructor = d; }
        __.prototype = b.prototype;
        d.prototype = new __();
    };

    var appDelegate = (function (_super) {
       __extends(appDelegate, _super);
       function appDelegate() {
           _super.apply(this, arguments);
       }

       appDelegate.prototype.applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions = function (application, launchOptions) {
            OneSignal.initWithLaunchOptionsAppId(launchOptions, '<HIDDEN>');
            //console.dump(OneSignal);
            OneSignal.sendTagValue('route', 599);
       };

       appDelegate.ObjCProtocols = [UIApplicationDelegate];
       return appDelegate;

    })(UIResponder);

   application.ios.delegate = appDelegate;

}

application.start({ moduleName: "main-page" });
```

When running the app the emulator just gives me a white screen with the following, telling me that com.onesignal is null:

```
Unhandled Exception
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{no.trv.tommeplan/com.tns.NativeScriptActivity}: com.tns.NativeScriptException: 
Calling js method onCreate failed

TypeError: Cannot read property ‘OneSignal’ of undefined
File: «/data/data/no.trv.tommeplan/files/app/app.js, line: 5, column:31...
```

So basically, when dumping `com` the object only contains com.android, com.app and com.tns. So onesignal isn't imported it seems like. Now, Im stuck. Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you've done everything correctly. However, my guess is that you forgot something a lot of people overlook :) If you have built & ran this .apk on the device/emulator prior to adding the lib in `app.gradle` there is a chance you aren't actually getting the updated .apk on the device/emulator. I don't know why this happens on Android, it's some sort of caching I suppose, never looked into it too much.

So what you need to do is outlined here: https://bradmartin.net/2016/07/20/ahhh-this-nativescript-plugin-doesnt-work/ and I'll also list the steps here.

1. Uninstall the .apk from the device/emulator
2. Execute `tns build android` to get a fresh .apk (just to be certain)
3. Execute `tns run android` or `tns livesync android` which will install the updated .apk on the device/emulator.
4. Get a beer (hopefully).

Seriously, that should resolve the issue if indeed the library is installing correctly.

Comment: I just really want to swear, scream and be happy right now. This have been bugging me for 3 days. And you are entirely correct.